# replace multiple values in a column for a single one

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a rather basic question. I have several values in a column that I would like to replace for a single one, for instance:

`a<-data.frame(T=LETTERS[5:20],V=rnorm(16,10,1))`

and I would like to change all "E", "S", "T" in T for "AB", so I tried

```
a[a$T==c("E","S","T")]<-"AB"
```

and it gives me several warnings, and ends up replacing all to "AB"

I think it has something to do with levels and level's labels but I was not able to replace only some of the values, I would have to re-label each. Sorry for the trouble, and thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use function `recode()` from library `car` to change values also for the factors.

```
library(car)
a$T<-recode(a$T,"c('E','S','T')='AB'")
```

If you need to replace different values with different other values then all statements can be written in one function call.

```
recode(a$T,"c('E','S','T')='AB';c('F','G','H')='CD'")
```

Comment: ...but why such an unfriendly interface (not blaming you @Didzis but the author). I read about `plyr::mapvalues` but I can't test it here on my old R version. I suppose `plyr::mapvalues(levels(a$T), c("E","S","T"), "AB")` might work if someone can give it a try.

Comment: @flodel mapvalues will work with some modification mapvalues(a$T, c("E","S","T"), rep("AB",3))

Comment: hello, this is really helpful! Thank you very much. Now I have realized I need to do this for several different groups of T, say (L,M,N). Is it possible to do it for all variables in a single line instead of doing it group by group?

Comment: @DidzisElferts Echoing your comment, a$T <- plyr::mapvalues(a$T, c("E","S","T"), rep("AB",3)) is more friendly and readable than car::recode(...)

Answer (score 4):

This would maintain your data structure (a factor like you guessed):

```
x <- levels(a$T)
levels(a$T) <- ifelse(x %in%  c("E","S","T"), "AB", x)
```

or

```
levels(a$T)[levels(a$T) %in%  c("E","S","T")] <- "AB"
```

---

**Edit**: if you have many such replacements, it is a little more complicated but not impossible:

```
from <- list(c("E","S","T"), c("J", "K", "L"))
to   <- c("AB", "YZ")

find.in.list <- function(x, y) match(TRUE, sapply(y, `%in%`, x = x))
idx.in.list  <- sapply(levels(a$T), find.in.list, from)
levels(a$T)  <- ifelse(is.na(idx.in.list), levels(a$T), to[idx.in.list])

a$T
#  [1] AB F  G  H  I  YZ YZ YZ M  N  O  P  Q  R  AB AB
# Levels: AB F G H I YZ M N O P Q R
```

Comment: +1. this is the right answer, rather than messing around with character class.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want factors there ???
If not (I think you do not) do `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`
So it is much simpler than that... => `a[a$T %in% c("E","S","T"),"T"]<-"AB"`

Comment: If T is factor (as in this case) this will give NA values not the AB.

Comment: Ohhhh !!! this is because my `options()$stringAsFactors==FALSE`, since `R.2.12.x` `R` R maintain hash tables for strings I think there is no need for factors in those cases...